# Compiler Error with static map and std::function using VS2012

Tags: c++11, visual-studio-2012, boost

I am trying to use a static `std::map` with an `enum` as key and a `std::function` as value. The static map is initialized using `boost::assign::map_list_of` from boost 1.52. I am using boost to do this because VS2012 does not know of c++11 initializer lists. My code works great on [wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/aZY4pSPbXeSQUcs2)

Here is what my code looks like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <functional>
#include <utility>

#include <boost/assign/list_of.hpp>

namespace ba = boost::assign;

class Foo
{
    public:    
    enum class MapKeys
    {
        Key1,
        Key2
    };

    typedef std::map<Foo::MapKeys, std::function<bool(Foo*, int i)>> fooMap;

    bool key_based_action(Foo::MapKeys m, int i) {
        return((Foo::myMap.at(m))(this, i));
    }

    private:

    static const Foo::fooMap myMap ;

    bool key1_handler(int i) {
        if (i > 0) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    bool key2_handler(int i) {
        if (i < 0) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

};

//const Foo::fooMap Foo::myMap = 
//{
//    {Foo::MapKeys::Key1, std::mem_fn(&Foo::key1_handler)},
//    {Foo::MapKeys::Key2, std::mem_fn(&Foo::key2_handler)}
//};

const Foo::fooMap Foo::myMap = 
    ba::map_list_of(Foo::MapKeys::Key1, std::mem_fn(&Foo::key1_handler))
    (Foo::MapKeys::Key2, std::mem_fn(&Foo::key2_handler));

int main(void) 
{
    Foo f;
    if(f.key_based_action(Foo::MapKeys::Key1, 1))
        std::cout << "Key1 returned true" << std::endl;
    if(f.key_based_action(Foo::MapKeys::Key2, 1))
        std::cout << "Key2 returned true" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And the error message:

```
1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xrefwrap(518): error C2248: "std::_Callable_base<_Ty,_Indirect>::operator =": Kein Zugriff auf private Member, dessen Deklaration in der std::_Callable_base<_Ty,_Indirect>-Klasse erfolgte.
1>         with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=bool (__thiscall Foo::* )(int),
1>              _Indirect=false
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xrefwrap(331): Siehe Deklaration von 'std::_Callable_base<_Ty,_Indirect>::operator ='
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=bool (__thiscall Foo::* )(int),
1>              _Indirect=false
1>          ]
1>          Diese Diagnose trat in der vom Compiler generierten Funktion "std::_Callable_pmf<_Ty,_Memty> &std::_Callable_pmf<_Ty,_Memty>::operator =(const std::_Callable_pmf<_Ty,_Memty> &)" auf.
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=bool (__thiscall Foo::* )(int),
1>              _Memty=Foo
1>          ]
```

It says something like no access on private members declared in `std::_Callable_base<_Ty,_Indirect>`.

As this works with gcc / clang and later versions of visual studio (tested with VS2015CE and boost 1.63) I suppose this is some kind of Bug / missing feature in VS2012. So I could solve this by not using a static map but the object lifetime holding the map is quite short and the map would be initialized over and over again. Any hint how I could do this with a static map and VS2012 (I have to use this version, there is no way of changing this)?

Comment: Could you perhaps switch to `boost::function`?

Comment: Thats actually not a bad idea. I'll try this today and report back, thanks!

Comment: @DanMašek With boost::function it does work. Thank you very much. If you provide this as an answer I will gladly accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this problem for me was to use `boost::function` as [Dan Masek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3962537/dan-ma%C5%A1ek) suggested.

Here is the updated code and I have also updated the [wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/B2hzGMuuCda4Fjww) example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <utility>

#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/assign/list_of.hpp>

namespace ba = boost::assign;

class Foo
{
    public:    
    enum class MapKeys
    {
        Key1,
        Key2
    };

    typedef std::map<Foo::MapKeys, boost::function<bool(Foo*, int i)>> fooMap;

    bool key_based_action(Foo::MapKeys m, int i) {
        return((Foo::myMap.at(m))(this, i));
    }

    private:

    static const Foo::fooMap myMap ;

    bool key1_handler(int i) {
        if (i > 0) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    bool key2_handler(int i) {
        if (i < 0) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

};

//const Foo::fooMap Foo::myMap = 
//{
//    {Foo::MapKeys::Key1, std::mem_fn(&Foo::key1_handler)},
//    {Foo::MapKeys::Key2, std::mem_fn(&Foo::key2_handler)}
//};

const Foo::fooMap Foo::myMap = 
    ba::map_list_of(Foo::MapKeys::Key1, &Foo::key1_handler)
    (Foo::MapKeys::Key2, &Foo::key2_handler);

int main(void) 
{
    Foo f;
    if(f.key_based_action(Foo::MapKeys::Key1, 1))
        std::cout << "Key1 returned true" << std::endl;
    if(f.key_based_action(Foo::MapKeys::Key2, 1))
        std::cout << "Key2 returned true" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```